# SQLite crash insert accented text iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, diacritics

I've a problem with sqlite. When i try to insert text with accent like "Géo", the app crash, without error, on this line :

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, request, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK
```

The app crash only when i try to insert in my database text with accent...

I tried to do [myVarString UT8String] but it changes nothing.

Someone has an idea ?

Thx,

EDIT :

Found the stupid error, in one of my request i used ASCIIencoding instead of UTF8.

Comment: When you try this insert on the SQLite command-line interface, what error do you get?

Comment: When a command fails on the SQLite command-line interface, it will always display an error. E.g., if I type `select from my_table;`, I'll get something like: `Error: near "from": syntax error`.

Comment: I found this - new - stupid error... in one of my request, I used ASCII for encoding instead of UT8...

Thx for the help,